# запрос json через asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Вчера мне посоветали изучить AsyncTask для запроса json, изучил, но ничего не понял, как мне распарсить json через AsyncTask.Json на сервере.

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import org.json.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.AdapterView.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
String[] links, names;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String json = "[{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.vk.com\",\"name\":\"VK\"}, {\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.google.com\",\"name\":\"Google\"},{\"id\":1,\"link\":\"http://www.yandex.ru\",\"name\":\"Yandex\"}]";
    try{
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
    int size = array.length();
    links = new String[size];
    names = new String[size];
    for(int n = 0; n < size; n++) {
        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(n);
        links[n] = obj.getString("link");
        names[n] = obj.getString("name");
}
} catch (JSONException e){
    Log.d("$", e.toString());
}
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(links[position]));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: для начала вот эта фраза "изучить AsyncTask для запроса json" ничего не понятно, 1. асинктаска позволяет делать запросы не в основном потоке, так как в основном нельзя. 2. json это формат обмена данными и 3. что это за урл "[{\"id\":1,\"l ....

Comment: ой там должно быть String json

Comment: По вашим вопросам ясно, что у вас нет минимального понимания о программировании и о android в частности, тут не пишут код за вас, а помогают с конкретными вопросами. Не ленитесь, почитайте, поучитесь, а потом смело задавать вопросы. http://startandroid.ru/ -  весьма понятно и достаточно.

Comment: А где Asynctask то и причем тут сервер?

Comment: @temq Мне надо распарсить json с сервера, мне сказали использовать библиотеки retrofit или voilley, но еще можно без библиотек,  с помощью AsyncTask, через httpurlconection, но как я не знаю, в этом коде он парсит вставленную json

Comment: Ну т.е вы хотите что бы за вас написали код, а вы бы скопировали его себе и подставили только свою ссылку на сервер? Просто я тут ни вижу хотя бы минимального намека на попытку сделать получение данных с сервера или хотябы реализовать asynctask.

Comment: Да. именно этого я и хочу, что бы изучить код, и в дальнейшом не задавать таких тупых вопросов